# Can I just copy an application from a MAC and paste it to another MAC?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, applications

As the title suggest, can I just copy and paste an application to my new MAC instead of downloading them all over again? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [migration assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5872?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) first.  It will move everything you need from your old mac. (OS 10.6.8 or later)

Many applications have data in the /Library/Application Support folder or the ~/Library/Application Support folder as well as prefeferences and other scattered support files that would all need to be moved.

Comment: This is very true.

Answer (score 1):

Most applications downloaded from the Mac App Store are transferable to another Mac, either by network or removable media (USB, etc).

You can copy the applications to your new Mac.

Comment: Okay mate, I'll try it first and see if it worked. Thanks :)